# Set of all matrix of rank $ r $ is open set in $ M_n (\mathbb { R })$

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, metric-spaces

I have no idea how to start it. Actually I have no idea which matrix in $ M_n (\mathbb {R})$ are  of rank $ r $. I know all basic result about it. please help me.

Answer (score 6):

Let $A$ be a matrix of rank $r$. There is a submatrix of size $r\times r$ whose determinant is different from $0$. A small perturbation of $A$ will keep this determinant different from $0$.

Comment: Seems that small perturbation still can make the rank bigger.

Comment: @Evgeny: Yeah, I don't think this statement is true except for $r=n$. It's obviously false for $r=0$.

Comment: @Evgeny You are right (actually, there is an invertible matrix in each neighborhood of $A$). The correct statement should be the openess of the matrices of rank $\geqslant r$.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Yes I thought too that rank $\geqslant r$ matrices should be open. Hope that this don't make a contradiction with initial question :)